# Line formating issue telnet powershell/ command promt

Tags: powershell, cmd, command, putty

Hi I am having problem with connecting to telnet all my lines are broken like this on any terminal except putty:

`First line of text
                  Second line
                             Third line`

Which makes it next to impossible to read anything.. Only place I have managed to display correctly is using putty cmd and turning on both options:

implicit LF in every CR
implicit CR in every LF

I would like to find out if there is way to do this either in powershell or command promt.. And preferably through interface itself.

I did turn on in command promt crlf but it had no effect. Any suggestions would be very much welcome after hours of trying to find solution I am losing my mind.

Comment: Why are you still using telnet??

Comment: I am suing telnet because its how I connect to internal application to debug source

Comment: So you're remoting into specific applications? or are you remoting into the server itself?

Comment: Into specific application once I connect to that application I get set of instructions and console which I can use to execute set of commands like logs ect. And able to debug application